# Exception playing AU file on Windows 11 but works on Windows 10 (same code)

Tags: java, audio

Using the following program to execute an .au file with a sound.

Compiled and executed using Java 17.0.7

On Windows 10, a sound is generated.

On Windows 11, an exception is returned.

**Exception**

Error with playing the sound.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No line matching interface Clip supporting format PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, stero, 4 bytes/frame, big-endian is supported.

Here is the code being executed.

```
import java.io.File; 
import java.io.IOException; 
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream; 
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem; 
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip; 
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException; 
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException; 

public class SimpleAudioTest 
{ 

    Long currentFrame; 
    static Clip clip; 
    String status; 
    AudioInputStream audioInputStream; 
    static String filePath; 
    public SimpleAudioTest() 
        throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, 
        IOException, LineUnavailableException 
    { 
        audioInputStream = 
        AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("C:\\Temp\\mySound.au").getAbsoluteFile());
        AudioFormat format = audioInputStream.getFormat();
        
        if ((format.getEncoding() == AudioFormat.Encoding.ULAW) ||
        (format.getEncoding() == AudioFormat.Encoding.ALAW))
        {
            AudioFormat tmp = new AudioFormat(
            AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED,
            format.getSampleRate(),
            format.getSampleSizeInBits() * 2,
            format.getChannels(),
            format.getFrameSize() * 2,
            format.getFrameRate(),
            true);
            
            audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(tmp, audioInputStream);
            format = tmp;
        }
        
        
        clip = AudioSystem.getClip(); 
        clip.open(audioInputStream); 
        clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY); 
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        System.out.println("Running the test");
        try
        { 
            filePath = "Your path for the file"; 
            SimpleAudioTest audioPlayer = 
                            new SimpleAudioTest(); 
            
            clip.start(); 
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
            sc.close(); 
        } 
        
        catch (Exception ex) 
        { 
            System.out.println("Error with playing sound."); 
            ex.printStackTrace(); 
        
        } 
    } 

}
```

Is there something different with Windows 11 ?

Comment: Does it work if you remove that entire `if` block?

Comment: No because the file is in ULAW format which doesn't work and that code is required to convert it.

Comment: It might help to print out the available playback formats, with something like `for (Line.Info info : AudioSystem.getSourceLineInfo(new Line.Info(SourceDataLine.class))) { System.out.println(info); for (AudioFormat format : ((DataLine.Info) info).getFormats()) { System.out.println("  " + format); } }`

Comment: @VGR Thanks. On Windows 10 it prints out the various formats, but on Windows 11, nothing is printed. Does that mean Windows 11 no longer supports it or is it now something that needs to be installed. Don't recall having to manually install it on Windows 10 to get it working.

Comment: I just tried it in Windows 11 and it printed three lines, each supporting eight audio formats.  I didn’t install anything special.  Forgive me for falling back on such a tired and overused suggestion, but… is it possible you just need to update your audio driver?

Comment: @VGR These systems are locked down, but the above code is enough to justify this being an OS issue and not a Java issue by not having the drivers available. Thanks. Will definitely keep that code for future use.